# How to set margin/padding percentage in terms of height(by default its in terms of width) in CSS..?

Tags: css, margin

Usually if we specify `margin-top:10%;/*(say for eg.)*/`
then margin-top will be 10% of pages width, but i want 10% of pages height.

Comment: EDIT: Oh Shnitzel... I was wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/dhCAg/ (resize it to see).

Comment: @Joseph I see, never noticed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, a margin percentage will *always* be in terms of the width of the containing element. That's how it's defined and that's how it should work. The only flexible margin you can use for top and bottom is the `auto` value which will let the browser automatically calculate what the top and/or bottom margin should be. There's no way to make that percentage apply to the height of the element. The `padding-top` declaration works in the same way concerning percentages.

You'll probably have to add an extra division of some sort above it that has a height with the percentage of 'margin' you want to be there. Not sure how well this would work out though.

Comment: thanx for spending ur valuable time for me bro :)